# startservice in android 3.0

Tags: android

hello this is my code it give error only in android 3.0 simulator
please help me..

private PersistentLocationManager persistentLocationManager;

```
Thread xtifyThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            persistentLocationManager = new PersistentLocationManager(
                    context);
            persistentLocationManager
                    .setNotificationIcon(R.drawable.icon);
            persistentLocationManager
                    .setNotificationDetailsIcon(R.drawable.icon);
            boolean trackLocation = persistentLocationManager
                    .isTrackingLocation();
            boolean deliverNotifications = persistentLocationManager
                    .isDeliveringNotifications();
            if (trackLocation || deliverNotifications) {
                persistentLocationManager.startService();
            }

        }
    });
    xtifyThread.start();
```

i do debuging then i got error after this line : persistentLocationManager.startService(); but only in android 3.0 except this in all simulator work perfectly

error log

05-17 16:38:44.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(293): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.xtify.android.sdk.MainService: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: provider=network
05-17 16:38:44.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(293):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2034)
05-17 16:38:44.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(293):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2500(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-17 16:38:44.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(293):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1047)
05-17 16:38:44.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(293):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-17 16:38:44.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(293):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
05-17 16:38:44.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(293):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
05-17 16:38:44.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(293):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-17 16:38:44.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(293):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
05-17 16:38:44.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(293):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
05-17 16:38:44.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(293):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
05-17 16:38:44.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(293):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-17 16:38:44.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(293): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: provider=network
05-17 16:38:44.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(293):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1326)
05-17 16:38:44.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(293):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1276)
05-17 16:38:44.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(293):     at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.requestLocationUpdates(ILocationManager.java:646)
05-17 16:38:44.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(293):     at android.location.LocationManager._requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:582)
05-17 16:38:44.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(293):     at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:446)
05-17 16:38:44.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(293):     at com.xtify.android.sdk.MainService.g(Unknown Source)
05-17 16:38:44.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(293):     at com.xtify.android.sdk.MainService.onCreate(Unknown Source)
05-17 16:38:44.006: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(293):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2024)

Comment: If you run it without debugging - does it work OK?

Comment: no when i run then also does not work

Comment: @moon: As I told you yesterday, try http://help.xtify.com.

Comment: @Moon - please edit your answer with the log, don't put it in comments, it's hard to read.

Comment: @CommonsWare - Yes i was also posted this on that site. but not getting any satisfactory answer